# Structure of table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to create table of below `JSON`.

```
{
    "store_nbr": "1234",
    "sls_dt": "2014-01-01 00:00:00",
    "Items": [{
        "sku": "3456",
        "sls_amt": "9.99",
        "discounts": [{
            "disc_nbr": "1",
            "disc_amt": "0.99"
        }, {
            "disc_nbr": "2",
            "disc_amt": "1.00"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Can anyone help me what would be the structure of this JSON on BigQuery ? and How I can retrieve data using SQL query ?

Comment: It is not clear what exactly is this. Can you please clarify - do you have already table where one of the field has such json as a string value and you need to parse / extract this value to respective key/values and output it into another table? or something else. Please elaborate a little on your case

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant As of now I have no table, I want to create table using this JSON, now I am wondering what would be the structure of my table and how I can read values of it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering what would be the structure of my table?

Try below for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 
        1234 AS store_nbr, 
        DATE('2014-01-01 00:00:00') AS sls_dt, 
        [STRUCT(
            3456 AS sku, 
            9.99 AS sls_amt, 
            [STRUCT<disc_nbr INT64, disc_amt FLOAT64>
                 (1, 0.99), 
                 (2, 1.00)
            ] AS discounts
        )] AS items
)
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
```

The structure of table here is:

[image]

or if to look in Web UI:

[image]

> How I can read values of it?

It is really depends on what exactly and how you want to "read" out of this data!

For example if you want to calc total discount per each sale - it can looks as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 
    1234 AS store_nbr, 
    DATE('2014-01-01 00:00:00') AS sls_dt, 
    [STRUCT(
      3456 AS sku, 9.99 AS sls_amt, [STRUCT<disc_nbr INT64, disc_amt FLOAT64>(1, 0.99), (2, 1.00)] AS discounts
    )] AS items
)
SELECT 
  t.*, 
  (SELECT SUM(disc.disc_amt) FROM UNNEST(item.discounts) AS disc) AS total_discount
FROM yourTable AS t, UNNEST(items) AS item
```

I recommend you first to complete your "exercise" with table creation and actually get data into it, so than you can ask specific questions about query you want to build.
But this should be a new post so you do not mix all together as an all-in-one question, as such type of questions usually not welcomed here on SO